# Powershell not handling arguments in function properly

Tags: powershell

Any idea why my script is acting funny?

I am passing it some arguments, but it doesn't seem to be assigning them to the correct variables. E.g.

```
function test($a, $b, $c){

    write-host "A: " $a
    write-host "B: " $b
    write-host "C: " $c

    $sum = $a + $b + $c

    write-host "The sum is: " $sum
}

test(1,2,3)
```

Is giving the following output:

```
A:  1 2 3
B: 
C: 
The sum is:  1 2 3
```

What gives?

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dammit.

Should have been using

```
test 1 2 3
```

to invoke the function.

Thanks anyway!

Ben